# Creating/setting an active default link when page loads but removing active when others are clicked

Tags: javascript, jquery

As I typed this question I noticed similar question but my approach is different. I did read them but not what I am trying to do, however I did get some ideas.

I have three links (anchor tags) on my page, I am using JQuery to toggle a class between the links based on the link the user clicks. The link becomes active when clicked and I added Cookies to remember the user action.

What I really want to do is set the first link or the link with, example: ID equals one; to be the default. I want the same class (activeLink) which I am using to make the links active to apply to the default. When others are click, the class is than removed and the clicked link becomes active.

That's what I don't know how to do.

My page is a single page.
**HTML:**

```
<ul class="yeahBaby">
<li><a id="one" href="#/">Make me default</a></li>
<li><a id="two" href="#/">Example</a></li>
<li><a id="three" href="#/">Example</a></li>
</ul>
```

**JQUERY:**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var idActive = $.cookie('cookieActive');

    if (idActive) {
        $('#'+idActive).addClass('activeLink');
    }

    $('.yeahBaby li a').click(function() {
        var id = $(this).attr('id');

        $(".yeahBaby li a").removeClass("activeLink");
        $(this).addClass("activeLink");
        $.cookie('cookieActive', id); //Save anchor id as cookie
        $.cookie('cookieActive', id, { expires: 10000}); 
    });
});
```

**CSS:**

```
<style type="text/css">
.activeClass{
color: #999;
}
</style>
```

Thanks everyone!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set the link with `id="one"` as default in your HTML.

```
<ul class="yeahBaby">
    <li><a id="one" href="#/">Make me default</a></li>
    <li><a id="two" href="#/">Example</a></li>
    <li><a id="three" href="#/">Example</a></li>
</ul>​​​
```

Then in jQuery:

```
// Upon loading the page set default .activeLink
$(window).load(function() {
    // If cookie exists
    if( $.cookie('active') !== null ) {
        // Add .activeLink to last the class in cookie
        $.cookie('active').addClass('activeLink');
    } else {
        // Else set on default
        $('#one').addClass('activeLink');
    }
});

// Bind click event to each anchor in your list
$('.yeahBaby li a').bind('click', function(e) {
    // Remove .activeLink class from current active link
    $('.activeLink').removeClass('activeLink');
    // Add .activeLink to the link just clicked
    $(this).addClass('activeLink');
    // Create cookie
    $.cookie('active', $(this));
    return false;
});​
```

See it in action here: [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/AcQsc/1/)

-- Update --

See above for addition cookies using the [jQuery $.cookie plugin](https://github.com/carhartl/jquery-cookie/).

Comment: Hello ValJas, what about the Cookies? When you click on the next link the active links moves as expected, but when you reload the page, the cookies remembers the first link so both are now active.

Comment: Thanks very much, I am not to great with this so I have to play around with the code. I am a little confused by the If statement since I already have a Cookie in the first code I posted. S are there two cookies? Where are we getting Active Cookie?

Comment: You're implementation is fine actually, although you'll want to remove the class from the default if you have a cookie as well, otherwise it will set the element in the cookie as active but leave the active on the default as well. There doesn't need to be two cookies, I was just trying include an example with comments to explain a little bit more what was going on.